# Doing non-blocking I/O on a TCP socket in a restricted environment

Tags: perl, sockets, cgi

I trying to write some relatively simple library functions to emulate `LWP::UserAgent`'s `get` method, because [LWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_for_WWW_in_Perl) and associated libraries are not available on some of our hosting. All I can rely on are Perl's core functions and even some of those are restricted, but I do appear to have access to sockets, fork, signals and the like.

I have so far managed to create a simple client and server (the server is just for testing) that can send and receive data. The problem is I want to set a timeout on the whole `get` operation like in LWP, but my initial attempts have been fruitless. The following does not work and I don't believe it can work, but I will post it just in case it can be fixed:

```
sub grab {
    my($addr, $port, $timeout) = @_;
    my $it;

    eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
            die "alarm\n";
        };

        alarm $timeout if $timeout;

        my $iaddr = inet_aton($addr)
        or die "client no host: $!";
        my $paddr = sockaddr_in($port, $iaddr)
        or die "client sockaddr_in: $!";
        my $proto = getprotobyname("tcp");

        socket(Client, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto)
        or die "Client socket: $!";

        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
            close(Client);
            die "alarm\n";
        };

        connect(Client, $paddr)
        or die "Client connect: $!";
        while(my $line = <Client>) {
            $it .= $line;
        }

        print alarm(0), " seconds left \n";
        close(Client) or die "Client close: $!";
    };
    if($@) {
        die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";
    }

    return $it;
}
```

The alarm signal seems to get ignored by the likes of connect, read and possibly some of the others. I resorted to reading the LWP source code after this failed to work - because I felt like I was barking up the wrong tree - and found the following, amongst other gems, in `strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm`:

```
sub sysread {
    my $self = shift;
    if (my $timeout = ${*$self}{io_socket_timeout}) {
        die "read timeout" unless $self->can_read($timeout);
    }
    else {
        # since we have made the socket non-blocking we
        # use select to wait for some data to arrive
        $self->can_read(undef) || die "Assert";
    }
    sysread($self, $_[0], $_[1], $_[2] || 0);
}

sub can_read {
    my($self, $timeout) = @_;
    my $fbits = '';
    vec($fbits, fileno($self), 1) = 1;
    SELECT:
    {
        my $before;
        $before = time if $timeout;
        my $nfound = select($fbits, undef, undef, $timeout);
        if ($nfound < 0) {
            if ($!{EINTR} || $!{EAGAIN}) {
                # don't really think EAGAIN can happen here
                if ($timeout) {
                    $timeout -= time - $before;
                    $timeout = 0 if $timeout < 0;
                }
                redo SELECT;
            }
            die "select failed: $!";
        }
        return $nfound > 0;
    }
}
```

So it looks like it works round some of the limitations of other subroutines by using select? It also doesn't appear to fork or use signals and strictly speaking it still blocks occasionally, but it tries to make sure that it won't block for long? I feel like I should copy the gist of this code and create a simplified version for my specific needs, but I am starting to get pretty wary of running into minefields. Also note that I am developing on Windows, but deploying to Linux/nix* as well as maybe Windows in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be precious little you can simplify: the core of it is using the 5 arg version of select as perldoc -f select neatly explains (abstract at bottom of answer).

But I fail to understand your endeavour unless it is for learning purposes: you can grab LWP and package it with your other custom libraries with basically NO effort, bar a "use lib qw(foo/bar)" at the top of you program. I doubt that you can come up with something that's substantially simpler while also being correct from a protocol standpoint.

If you do not want to use select() than you could fork, do the get in the client and have the parent kill the child at timeout (you could even use threads, if you felt so inclined) but that's bizarre, not to mention unnecessary.

Cheers,

--

perldoc -f select

```
   select RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT
           This calls the select(2) system call with the bit masks specified, 
           which can be constructed using "fileno" and "vec", along these lines:

               $rin = $win = $ein = ’’;
               vec($rin,fileno(STDIN),1) = 1;
               vec($win,fileno(STDOUT),1) = 1;
               $ein = $rin │ $win;

           If you want to select on many filehandles you might wish to write a subroutine:

               sub fhbits {
                   my(@fhlist) = split(’ ’,$_[0]);
                   my($bits);
                   for (@fhlist) {
                       vec($bits,fileno($_),1) = 1;
                   }
                   $bits;
               }
               $rin = fhbits(’STDIN TTY SOCK’);

           The usual idiom is:

               ($nfound,$timeleft) =
```

Comment: Well, thank you for telling me I am on the right course with select, if that is what you are actually telling me. I know that the premise of my question is silly, but I am not in control of the environment I am coding in. You can assume that bundling LWP and its dependencies is not an option. When I say simplify, I mean that I am not going to reimplement LWP and all of its dependencies (e.g HTTP module) in their entirety. I don't need it to understand more HTTP than the absolute basics so my library will be significantly smaller than LWP and could be copied into another script if necessary.

Comment: In fact select is the way to go. But methinks that "I do not need to understand mor HTTP..." will bite you at some point. @the very least, a GET client that's going to be even remotely useful will need to handle 3xx redirects - and that's only for starters.

Comment: None of the servers I will be accessing should throw a redirect or proxy at me, it should generally be OK 200 or my script fails and gives up (aren't HTTP proxies supposed to be transparent for the most part?). If that is not the case then, well I guess I have always secretly, deep down, wanted to re-implement a good part of the HTTP protocol in Perl.

Comment: Leaving redirects aside - proxying is definitely not transparent at the HTTP level, when it is client side - i.e. on your side - but you should know it already if you  are behind a proxy. Unless it is a "transparent proxy" that is.